# After latest security patches updation of ubuntu 20.04 version, Domain Joined computers are not recognised as member

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, login, samba

After latest security patches updation of ubuntu 20.04 version, Domain Joined computers are not recognised as member. Even Local admin account only login can possible. Last two days facing the issue. if anyone please share the solutions..

Is it possible to revoke the yesterday installed patches?...